# Не хочет записывать список в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Только начал изучать потоки в пайтоне. Вот задание:Главный поток программы должен генерировать строки случайного содержания и помещать их в конец списка. Дочерний поток №1 должен выдавать текущее состояние списка на экран. Дочерний поток №2 пробуждается каждые пять секунд и сортирует список в лексикографическом порядке и сохраняет в файл.
Все работает, кроме записи в файл. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```
import threading
import time
from random import choice
from string import ascii_letters


def sortirovka():
    f = open("qw.txt", "w")
    while 4 > 0:
        time.sleep(5)
        spicok.sort(key=str.lower)
        f.write(str(spicok))


def printer():
    f = open("qw.txt", "r")
    while 4 > 0:
        print(spicok)
        time.sleep(1)



spicok = []
t = threading.Thread(target=sortirovka)
p = threading.Thread(target=printer)
t.start()
p.start()
while 4 > 0:
    spicok.append(''.join(choice(ascii_letters) for i in range(12)))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В соседнем ответе всё правильно написали про то, что после записи файлы нужно закрывать. Ошибка того ответа в том, что нет никакого смысла заворачивать в менеджер контекста бесконечный цикл, т.к. выполнение программы никогда не дойдёт до закрытия файла.

Файл нужно открывать и закрывать на каждой итерации. То есть если используется менеджер контекста, то он весь целиком должен быть внутри цикла:

```
def sortirovka():
    while 4 > 0:
        time.sleep(5)
        with open("qw.txt", "w") as f:
            spicok.sort(key=str.lower)
            f.write(str(spicok))
```

А в функции printer вообще нет смысла открывать файл, так как там вы его не используете.

Answer (score 0):

Запись скорее всего тоже работает, просто файл не закрывается, в коде нет `f.close()`.

Чтобы не забывать закрывать файл можно использовать [менеджер контекста](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/with-as-menedzhery-konteksta.html):

```
with open("qw.txt", "w") as f:
    while 4 > 0:
        time.sleep(5)
        spicok.sort(key=str.lower)
        f.write(str(spicok))
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло(